# Determine if first char of string is upper or lower

Tags: c#, string, char

I'm trying to determine whether the first char of the "sentence" string is capital or not. The program runs fine, but test run gives an array index out of range error. I can't understand the problem.

```
public class CapitalOrNot
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string sentence = "Asdafasda";
        string UpOrLow = UpperOrLower(sentence);
        Console.WriteLine("First char is " + UpOrLow);
    }

    public static string UpperOrLower(string mj)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(mj[0]))
        {
            mj = "upper";
        }
        else mj = "lower";

        return mj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/Pft0pL and that was a straight copy paste

Comment: Could your test be feeding you an empty string? This would cause `mj[0]` to throw that error.

Comment: The code works fine; http://csharppad.com/gist/34ac6b62a620acefb634

Comment: doogle, I think that is the case. My teacher said that I shouldn't do it this way, but didn't give any input what I should do. He said I should process the empty string some other way.

Comment: What if the string starts with a space? IsLower = false, IsUpper = false...

Comment: Good point. Or what if it starts with some other character(s)? like: `_ < is this upper or lower?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check if the string is empty:

```
 public static string UpperOrLower(string mj)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mj))
         return "bad input";

     return char.IsUpper(mj[0]) ? "upper" : "lower";
 }
```

Comment: To me, `string.Any()` is a really strange way of not using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`. Does it have any benefits?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's a benefit.  I agree, `IsNullOrEmpty` gets the point across a bit better, and adds the null check.

Comment: This did the trick. I did think about IsNullOrEmpty, but didn't know how to take advantage of it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Again this doesn't work if the first char is not a letter IE a space

Comment: @Steve there are a lot of edge cases.  He asked why he was getting an error and this is the smallest code I can offer to demonstrate how to handle that specific case.

Comment: But adding a char.IsLetter and a test for IsNullOrWhiteSpace could be simple to add and to explain and, if you allow me to say so, it will be a lot better.

Comment: Test for `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mj)` and Add `char.IsLetter(mj[0]) && char.IsUpper(mj[0])` on the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using null conditional operator:

```
public static string UpperOrLower(string str)
{
    return (str?.Any()).GetValueOrDefault() ? (Char.IsUpper(str.First()) ? "upper" : "lower") : "bad input";
}
```

Comment: nice...   why use a local variable, when you can just return the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public class CapitalOrNot
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string sentence = "Asdafasda";

        if(sentence.Length > 0 && sentence != null)
        {
            string UpOrLow = UpperOrLower(sentence);
            Console.WriteLine("First char is " + UpOrLow);
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("You did not input a sentence");
        }
    }

    public static string UpperOrLower(string mj)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(mj[0]))
        {
            mj = "upper";
        }
        else mj = "lower";

        return mj;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't alter the main program, as this is an online program on my university website. I just have to code the subroutine.

Comment: Shouldn't `sentence.Length > 0 && sentence != null` replaced with `string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence)`?

Comment: Yeah, that's better.... I would use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentence)` since it essentially does the same thing but nicer.